# How do I specify DomainOverrideStrategy.OVERRIDE on a gcloud beta app domain-mappings request?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am using a Custom Domain for a Google Application project.  I have multiple projects and I use the same domain for each, although only one mapping is active at any time. Historically this has been as simple as Verifying the domain on the latest project and then Adding the domain.  The domain has then automatically switched to the new project. 
I have not used this approach for some months and when I tried it recently I got the messages

- www.xxxxx.com is already mapped to a project.
- xxxxx.com is already mapped to a project.

Research on StackOverflow suggests the use of the following command

- gcloud beta app domain-mappings create xxxxx.com

This does look the right thing to do, unfortunately the response to the command is:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.domain-mappings.create) App [aaaaaa] is the subject of a conflict: Domain 'xxxxx.com' is already mapped to another application. You must delete the existing domain mapping before you can re-map the domain, or you may specify 'DomainOverrideStrategy.OVERRIDE' on the request to force overwrite the existing mapping. Domain 'xxxxx.com' is currently mapped to an application on which you do not have permissions.

I do not want to use the delete approach since there will be a gap in service before the re-map.  I would like to use the OVERRIDE option but I cannot work out how to add it to the gcloud command and I cannot locate any documentation.

**Update 6Nov17**.
In the absence of an answer I have used the delete approach and it worked as expected.  The re-map was possible immediately after the mapping was deleted for the current app.  Unfortunately for some users access to the web page was not possible, or error messages were returned, for a while.  After about 10-15 minutes normal service was resumed.  For my web site a gap of 10-15 minutes is manageable.  This will not be true for many sites and I anticipate that Google Cloud will tidy up this procedure before it exits Beta.
If for some reason it is not possible to access the current app to delete the mapping then I guess deleting the app's subdomain information at the domain registrar will have the same effect, although it may be difficult to predict when the delete of the associated mapping will happen.
On the plus site the new automatic SSL provision worked flawlessly.

Comment: I had similar problem, too. Does this help? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.domainMappings/create#DomainOverrideStrategy
It seems like Google wants you to call a service API to override the domain rather than running in on gcloud command line. 
I was trying this API but I got 403 error for some reason.

Comment: The answer to this other question worked for me to solve this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49313083/413438