# Cloudrun Force Override flag not working as expected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Below command as per the documentation needs to map the custom domain to cloudrun service even if mapped to a different service. But currently, it is returning an error

```
gcloud beta run domain-mappings create --force-override  --service=ms-stutzen  --domain=stutzen.co  --region 'us-central1'
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.domain-mappings.create) Domain mapping to [stutzen.co] already exists in this region.
```

Is there any other command to perform deletion and remapping in a single command?

Comment: If you delete and recreate the domain mapping, does it work?

Comment: Yes as two commands delete and create works as expected.

Comment: @arvindwill Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav looking for the action in single command --force-override, instead of two different commands (Delete and Add). Delete and Add take more time and sometimes it fails for SSL when using the Proxy server(WAF) in front of the Cloudrun service

Answer (score 0):

You can able to delete the  existing domain mapping by the following command as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/domain-mappings/delete) for deletion:

Syntax:

```
gcloud beta run domain-mappings delete --domain=<your_domain>
```

Then you can create it again after deletion, there will be no conflicting.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.domainMappings/create#domainoverridestrategy) as mentioned here you may use '`DomainOverrideStrategy.OVERRIDE`'  to force overwrite the existing domain mapping.

You can refer to the [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46345759/error-domain-is-already-mapped-to-a-project-in-google-cloud-platform/49313083#49313083) where the whole description of adding this flag has been explained.

Comment: Is it possible to add this flag from Console while creating?

Comment: @arvindwill I have updated my answer by adding a stackoverflow answer thread , Hope it helps.

Comment: Using Managed platform. Is there any reason why  DomainOverrideStrategy.OVERRIDE are not mentioned in this document.  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/run/domain-mappings/create